# How to add a function to an existing object as a module in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am using the D3 library, which exposes a global object called `d3`.

I also have a code file which adds a function to this object, called `d3.tip`. However, this file is not in the format required for Node modules. I would like to convert it to a Node module.

If I assign the function to `module.exports.tip`, obviously it won't attach to the `d3` object. How do I write the Node module correctly for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you require you could do:

```
d3.tip = require("file").tip;
```